# FireMonkey property editor at runtime

Tags: delphi, properties, editor, runtime, firemonkey

In an HD form in FireMonkey, can I invoke the Brush property editor at runtime?

e.g. when the application is running, upon click of a button, I want to show the TBrush property editor in Modal. When the user selects the brush type, I want to apply it on the form or other components. Can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you mean brush style?

Answer (score 0):

The brush property editor is `TBrushDesigner` in unit `FMX.Design.Brush`. It is a design time editor.

I doubt it is possible to show it at run-time as it has design-time dependencies. But if you have the FMX source code, you can try to work around that.